# Is work item history query supported in Azure DevOps Services REST API?

Tags: azure-devops

I would like to query the addition/deletion of parent/child tasks of a ADO work item. I saw there is a "workItemHistory" link in the response of the example in the following page, which might be helpful to query the work item history.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work-items/get-work-item?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP

I tried it but there is no "workItemHistory" link in the response on my side. There are indeed links like "self", "workItemUpdates", "workItemRevisions", etc. in the response. Just no "workItemHistory" link. I tried to manually format such a link by changing the last word (e.g. "revisions") to "history"; but it did not work either (404 page not found was reported).

Is history query supported or not? Or is there any other REST API which could be used to query all change history of a work item? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is history query supported or not? Or is there any other REST API which could be used to query all change history of a work item?

Yes. You can use the Rest API: [Updates - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/updates/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/updates?api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

This API will return the old and new values of the fields changed in each history.

For example:

Remove links

[image]

Add link:

[image]

Or if you need to get the values of all fields in the work item in each history record, you can use the Rest API: [Revisions - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/revisions/list?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP)

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wit/workItems/{id}/revisions?$expand=all&api-version=7.1-preview.3
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this REST API, Kevin. I had a try and it works.